# Why appear this error when I delete all string to empty in react-native TextInput components?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native code in the below, when I use delete on keyboard to clean all string to empty in TextInput components, It always show the first error picture, and when I DISMISS the error and reinput string, it show the second error picture, anyone know what happened here and how to solve it?

## The render snippet

```
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>NickName</Text> 
      </View>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="NickName"
          onChangeText={(text) => SubjectStore.setDisplayName(text)}
          value={SubjectStore.displayName}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```

## The store

```
class SubjectStore {
  @observable user;
  @observable inSignupProcess;

  constructor(firebase) {
    this.user = null
  }

  @computed get displayName(){
    return this.user.displayName
  }

 @action setDisplayName(val){
   this.user.displayName = val
 }

}
```

## First error picture

[image]

## Second error picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is something related to how the onChangeText function is behaving with the way you're directly interesting with your store. Have you tried using just onChange()?  If that doesn't work, I'd try pulling the store interactions out into their own helper functions that are called and debugging from there.

[image]